# Creating a minimal Spotify Web Player window only containing the song title and like button

Tags: google-chrome, spotify

While listening to music on Spotify, I often find myself opening the Spotify window to check whether I have liked the current song, and to see what it is called. To make this easier, I would like a minimal Spotify player containing only the title of the song, the artist, and the like button, like this:

[image]

The first idea could be to use the [Spotify Web Player](https://open.spotify.com/) in a Chrome window (in web app mode) and then just make the window so small it only contains the above area. But the problem is, if you make the browser window this small, the desired area of the website is no longer visible. Is there a way to change this? (I am using Windows.)

Comment: Try to run it as an app : `chrome --app="https://play.spotify.com"`

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I know, but as I mentioned above, this alone does not solve the problem. If I make the window as small as I want it to be, the part of the website I want to see (with the name of the song and the like button) becomes hidden.

Comment: One can find some mini-players on the internet.

Comment: @harrymc Trust me, I have tried, and none of them seem to have a button for liking songs.